# how to remove all the running and queued tasks in ExecutorService and add new tasks into it?

Tags: java, executorservice

how to remove all the running and queued tasks in `ExecutorService` and add new tasks into it?

There is a `ExecutorService` to deal with the new tasks coming in each round.
If tasks are not done in this round, remove these old tasks and add news coming tasks in next round. `ExecutorService` will be reused in next round, so `ExecutorService` cannot be shutdown.
Anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

> how to remove all the running and queued tasks in ExecutorService and add new tasks into it?

Adding is easy - just call `submit`. Removing on the other hand is trickier - you can call `shutdownNow`. Javadoc:

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts theprocessing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.

However `shutdownNow()` will actually shut down the executor, so it'll refuse to accept new tasks. Also, note the word *attempts* in the Javadoc. Once a task started executing, there's no guarantee it can be easily stopped. Tasks can ignore `interrupt` and keep running.

If you want more granular control, don't use an `ExecutorService`. Instead, try a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which implements `ExecutorService`. In a `ThreadPoolExecutor` you have direct access to the queue of Runnables.

Comment: thanks, i will try ```ThreadPoolExecutor```